# Enviar un mail() por php y jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, formularios, mail

Estoy intentando realizar la prueba de un formulario html, el cual quiero que con ayuda de php envie un mail de prueba, y no estoy pudiendo lograrlo

Este es el UPDATE con el codigo corregido:

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['correo']) && isset($_POST['mensaje']) && isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['telefono'])){
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $mensajex = $_POST['mensaje'];   
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];


        $header = "From: " . $correo . " \r\n";
        $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
        $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
        
        $mensaje =

            $from = 'De: ' . $correo . " \r\n"; 
        $to = "exampleemail.com";
        $subject = "Nuevo mensaje de ". $nombre ." A través de tu sitio web, Ivoré Indumentaria";

        if(mail($to,$subject, $mensaje,$header)) {
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo 0;
        };
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
?>
```

Codigo Jquery con validaciones para email

```
    $('#send').on('click', (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    enviarMail();
    $('#formContact').trigger("reset")
});

function enviarMail(){
    $('.alertaNombre').css('display', 'none');
    $('.alertaMail').css('display', 'none');
    $('alertaTel').css('display', 'none');
    $('.alertaMsj').css('display', 'none');
    $('.alertaError').css('display', 'none');
    $('.alertaExito').css('display', 'none');

    let nombre = $("#name").val();
    let email = $("#email").val();
    let telefono = $("#tel").val();
    let mensaje = $("#message").val();
    let valido = 1;

    let validacionCorreo = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    if(nombre.length <2){
        $('.alertaNombre').css('display', 'block')
        valido = 0;
    }
    if(!validacionCorreo.test(email)){
        $('.alertaMail').css('display', 'block')
        valido = 0;
    }
    if(telefono.length < 8){
        $('.alertaTel').css('display', 'block')
        valido = 0;
    }
    if(mensaje.length <= 5){
        $('.alertaMsj').css('display', 'block')
        valido = 0;
    }
    if (valido == 1){
        let datos = 'nombre=' + nombre + '&correo=' + email + '&telefono=' + telefono + '&mensaje=' + mensaje;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../formulario.php",
            data: datos,
            success: function(res) {
                if(parseInt(res) == 1){
                    $('.alertaExito').css('display', 'block')
                } else{
                    $('.alertaError').css('display', 'block')
                }
            },
            error: function(res) {
                    $('.alertaError').css('display', 'block')
            }
        });
    }
}
```

El que desee usar el codigo, deberia tener en cuenta que esas alertas de css que tengo, fueron creadas a los fines de advertir al usuario cuando estaba dejando en blanco o completando con valores incorrectos el campo!

Espero que ayude y les sirva a las personas que tengan que enviar un formulario con php de manera muy simple

A tener en cuenta que mensaje queda en blanco porque borre el mensaje que tenia yo en mi computadora, pero ahi podrian probar de completar entre "" y con ; al final, el mensaje que quieran que llegue a su mail

Comment: usa phpmailer y resuelves ese problema de una vez, yo lo uso y me ahoro esos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Quita esto    $phone = "Telefono de Contacto" . $telefono; y pueba a ver.

Comment: estoy viendo que intentando ejecutar la prueba, me esta devolviendo un 404, como si no encontrara el archivo formulario.php, pero lo tengo en el directorio raiz

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto, resulta que fue una mala configuracion del xampp que no encontraba el path del archivo php. Ahora quiero hacer una consulta, teniendo en vistas mi codigo solo poniendo al name del input, y a las variables de php como correo, me da el mensaje de visto bueno, si la cambio por correox, por email o por cualquier otro que se les ocurra, me arroja la alerta que el mail no se puede enviar.

Answer (score -1):

Es necesario verificar dos cosas:

#### Primero verificar PHP

Te diría que primero hagas un `phpinfo();` para verificar que realmente tu xampp o incluso en tu hosting tengas PHP activo.
Para verificar el funcionamiento primero podes crear una página PHP, algo sencillo como tusitio.com/info.php

Ahora dentro de ese archivo PHP vacío ingresar la siguiente líneas:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Ahora solo queda guardar e ingresar en esa pagina y podrás ver todo lo que tenes activo para PHP en tu xampp o en tu hosting para el sitio, ya sean las funciones, versión de PHP y configuraciones.

#### Segundo, La función mail()

En PHP a veces esta deshabilitada. Si además intentaste esto no solo en tu servidor, sino en algún proveedor puede estar desactivada.

Ahora para asegurarte que `mail()` funciona debes hacer una prueba sencilla. Debes crear una página nueva, por ejemplo tusitio.com/unMail.php y pegando este código que escribo a continuación, debería salir un mensaje a tu correo a tu casilla de email:

```
//Reemplaza con tu @casilla de correos.

<?php
mail("micasilla@gmail.com", "Asunto de prueba", "Mensaje de prueba. Saludos.");
?>
```

Si no recibís ningún @correo, probablemente tengas que hablar con tu hosting para que active la `función mail()`.

En tu formulario veo que tenes faltantes de punto y coma (;)

Comment: estoy viendo que intentando ejecutar la prueba, me esta devolviendo un error 404, como si no encontrara el archivo formulario.php, pero lo tengo en el directorio raiz, es mas he movido el archivo y sigue sin funcionar, ya he corregido los problemas de ; que faltaban y he reescrito el codigo chequeando errores, pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Asegúrate de esta llamando al Formulario por su nombre correcto. Se llama formulario.html o Formualrio.php. Ademas, los nombres de los archivos son sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: ahora subo el codigo corregido, espero que te sirva